# I have let str="advanced frontend developer" as a string i need a output like "developer frontend advance" in reverse

Tags: javascript, string

```js
let str = "advanced frontend developer";

function reverseString(str) {
let data = str.split(' ');
let array = [];
data.forEach((element,index)=>{
    array.push(data[(data.length-1)-index])
});
console.log(...array)  
}

console.log(reverseString(str));
```

I have following above to reverse the string is there is any better way than this? please let me know.

Sorry i forgot to mention one thing with using **reverse()** function

Comment: one way is to just iterate over the string in reverse using the `for` loop and just `console.log` each character.

Comment: yeah for that i have use forEach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the result of `split` and rejoin:

```js
console.log("advanced frontend developer".split(" ").reverse().join(" "));

// want to use a loop?
const str = "advanced frontend developer".split(" ");
let i = str.length, result = [];
while (i--) {
  result.push(str[i]);
}
console.log(result.join(" "));
```

Using a function, you should return the result:

```js
const initialStr = "advanced frontend developer";
console.log(reverseStr(initialStr));

function reverseStr(str) { 
  return str.split(" ").reverse().join(" "); 
}

// or as arrow function
let reverseStrArrow = str => str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
console.log(reverseStrArrow(initialStr));
```

You can make this as complex as you want. Here a two extra loop solutions

```js
const str = "advanced frontend developer";
console.log(anotherReversalLoop(str));
console.log(anotherReversalLoop2(str));

// use array to store intermediate results
function anotherReversalLoop(str) {
  let result = [];
  let strTmp = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    if (str[i] === " ") {
      result.unshift(strTmp);
      strTmp = "";
    } else {
      strTmp += str[i];
    }
  }
  
  if (strTmp.length) {
    result.unshift(strTmp);
  }
  
  return result.join(" ");
}

// use string to store intermediate results
function anotherReversalLoop2(str) {
  let strResult = "";
  let strTmp = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    if (str[i] === " ") {
      strResult = `${strTmp} ${strResult}`;
      strTmp = "";
    } else {
      strTmp += str[i];
    }
  }
  
  if (strTmp.length) {
    strResult = `${strTmp} ${strResult}`;
  }
  
  return strResult;
}
```

Comment: ups, output is repoleved dnetnorf decnavda, first i saw split, revesrse join with a thought split at space..., so its easy to get  my upvote back :-)

Comment: without using reverse() and join() function we have to implement this. i have updated the question now.

Comment: @ArunkumarSubramani The first snippet in the answer contains a loop solution (`while`)

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript method chaining makes it lot more easier. Check the code below.

```
let str = "advanced frontend developer";
const reverseStr = str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
console.log(reverseStr); // developer frontend advanced
```

Comment: without using reverse() and join() function we have to implement this. i have updated the question now.